# Is this definition of the class P correct?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, polynomial-time

The definition of P is given by the union of all DTIME($n^k$) languages for $k >= 0$, where DTIME($n^k$) is the set of languages for which there exist a TM time-bounded by $T(n) = O(n^k)$. However, this is where my confusion lies - if $T(n) = O(n^k)$, then $T(n) <= c.n^k$ for $n >= N$; but does this mean the TM can run in, i.e. exponential time for inputs smaller than $N$? So that would mean that a language can be considered to be in P even if it cannot get decided by a TM that runs in polynomial time on all inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $T(n) \le c \cdot n^k$ for all $n \ge n_0$, where $n_0$ is a constant and $k \ge 0$.

Define $c' = c+\max_{n <n_0} T(n)$ and notice that, for all $n \ge 1$, the following holds:
$$
T(n) \le c \cdot n^k + \max_{n <n_0} T(n) \le \big(c + \max_{n <n_0} T(n) \big) n^k = c' \cdot n^k.
$$

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of $O$, i.e. in the asymptotic sense, the behavior for $n<N$ does not matter. What counts is the behavior towards infinity.

Think for a second: $n<10\implies 10000\log(n+1)>2^n$.